# NodeJS - Passport gives me 404 Error on login

Tags: node.js, express, passport.js

I've just implemented a simple login using Passport.js and passport-local and everything seems to be working, except for the final redirect.

When i log in with bad credentials, I get an error, as it's supposed to happen.

[image]

But when I log in with the correct credentials, I get a 404 error for no apparent reason. Sources are too widespread to put here, so you can find them on GitHub: https://github.com/JacobCZ/nodewiki (look into config/express, config/passport, models/user and views/auth)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I noticed a typo on your app/controllers/auth.js

```
router.post('/login', passport.authenticate('local-login', {
    sucecssRedirect: '/', // <== TYPO (successRedirect)
    failureRedirect: '/login',
    failureFlash: true
}));
```

That would probably explain it :)

Comment: I am such an idiot, thank you! That's what you get for using a "dumb" editor with Node, haha.

Comment: No worries. Glad I could help